# How to add success message to the email form?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, ghost-blog

I added the email signup form on the my website homepage. However, when user enters an email and clicks “submit” - there is no feedback whether it was sent successfully. Also, the input form is not cleared and typed in email stays there.

How to add a success/error message that would be shown below the form and automatically disappear after some time? Here is my form:

```
<form class="data-members-form" data-members-form>
  <input class="subscribe-form" data-members-email type="email" required="true" placeholder="Enter your email"/>
  <button class="subscribe-button" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

Here is a form from the [Ghost forum post](https://forum.ghost.org/t/ghost-membership-signup-form/17093) that hasn’t worked for me. I suppose there is no validation script:

```
<form data-members-form="signup" class="post-subscribe-form">
        <input data-members-email type="email" required="true" placeholder="email@address.net" class="post-subscribe-input"/>
        <button type="submit" title="Subscribe by email." class="post-subscribe-button">Subscribe</button>
        <div class="success">Success! Please click the link in we sent to your email to finalize your subscription.</div>
        <div class="error">Something went wrong. Contact <a href="mailto:placeholder@address.com">support</a>.</div>    
    </form>
```

I was going through the [SignupPage.js page](https://github.com/TryGhost/Portal/blob/main/src/components/pages/SignupPage.js) from Ghost Portal, but haven’t found anything useful. The code from [another tutorial](https://hooshmand.net/modifying-ghost-3-default-theme-casper/) haven't worked as well.

Adding `<form data-members-form class="success">...</form>` inside the form as per [Ghost Docs](https://ghost.org/docs/themes/members/?_ga=2.222742875.1304093396.1674339154-1118497926.1673087252) didn't work as well. Please, help.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Ghost Blog platform. Are you able to add your own Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS)?

Comment: @76484, Yes, I'm self-hosting and able to add my own files.

Comment: I think you can use a `redirect` in your backend code that will append either `success` or `error` to the address path, then add a `<script>` tag in your html page that contain a javascript to detect whether it's successful or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just having taken a look at the documentation you linked to, there are a couple of things that I think you can do quickly to get you closer to your goal.

First, under [Form States](https://ghost.org/docs/themes/members/#form-states), it states that CSS classes are add to the `form[data-members-form]` that correspond to the state of the form: `loading`, `success`, `error`.

You could leverage these classes to implement the showing/hiding of your success (`.success`) and error (`.error`) messages with some CSS.

First, we will set the default styling for both `.error` and `.success` to be `display: none`:

```
form[data-members-form] .error,
form[data-members-form] .success {
  display: none;
}
```

Next, we leverage the state classes of the `form[data-members-form]` so as to show our (with `display: block`) or `.error` and `.success` elements when the form is in the corresponding state:

```
form[data-members-form].error .error {
  display: block;
}

form[data-members-form].success .success {
  display: block;
}
```

Additionally, under [Error Messages](https://ghost.org/docs/themes/members/#error-messages), the docs state that an element with the attribute `data-members-error` will show and be populated with the error message when an error occurs. This means that you could add an empty element somewhere within your `form[data-members-form]` so that error messages will be shown to your user:

```
<p data-members-error></p>
```

As for clearing the form input and having the error and success messages disappear after some time duration, this would require some JavaScript, but I was unable to determine if there are APIs that would support, for example, hooking into the success handler of the form submission.